# is it possible to define the index of character in sentence with str.contain?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the data frame like this

```
          UPC   CPC freq_moc all_pat
        0   101 B22F    1.0  |US8193442|0|
        1   101 B82Y    2.0  |0|US8193442|US8088309|0|
        2   106 B22F    3.0  |US4219448|0|0|0|0|0|US8372734|US8809678|0|0
        3   106 B82Y    12.0 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|US5487792|0|0|US6538194|US68644
```

it is generated by this code

```
df_pat = df_pat[df_pat.all_pat.str.contains("0")]
df_pat
```

but I would like to ask is it possible to print out the row that contains |0| at the first index. for the expected result will be like

```
        UPC CPC freq_moc all_pat
    1   101 B82Y    2.0  |0|US8193442|US8088309|0|
    3   106 B82Y    12.0 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|US5487792|0|0|US6538194|US68644
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use str.startswith,

```
df_pat[df_pat.all_pat.str.startswith("|0|")]
```

You get

```
    UPC CPC    freq_moc all_pat
1   101 B82Y    2.0  |0|US8193442|US8088309|0|
3   106 B82Y    12.0 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|US5487792|0|0|US6538194|US68644
```

Comment: I see T_T thank you for your comment, i have never heard this function before TT